# SVG color different from page element to cursor

Tags: svg, colors, cursor, color-profile, srgb

I am replacing the cursor with an SVG, and it doesn't match the color of other elements on the page.

I have attached an image below (taken with my phone, because I cannot screenshot the cursor) Both SVGs were saved from the same file, both have a color value of #FF0000. This persists across all browsers.

The TOP button is applied as a background to the element.

How can I fix this?

[image: two SVGs that have a #FF0000 fill]

Comment: If you can provide the file, or a link to it, I could help you. I assume you've long since moved on.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the two colors appear to be identical on some monitors, but drastically different on others. In particular it's the Apple Color LCD profile on Macbook Pros that creates a drastic difference. Unfortunately this isn't something I will be able to solve.